# Uploading text to Wolfram Cloud with syntax highlighting?

Tags: wolfram-cloud

Via

```
text = "Some string..";
CloudExport[text, "Text", Permissions -> "Public"]
```

we can upload raw strings to the Wolfram Cloud; however, it's not very rich when it comes to formatting.

Is it possible to upload text to Wolfram Cloud that is parsed (with syntax highlighting, bold, italics, quotes, etc) in formats like:

- Markdown
- Org-Mode
- Shell/Bash code
- 
- ...

?

Answer (score 2):

There's probably a JS library about anything you want so you need to find one and either pre parse the string (`WebExectute`?) or deploy a template page that will hold your original content and parse it later.

Here is a small example based on https://github.com/markedjs/marked

```
$mdHtmlTemplate = StringTemplate@"<!doctype html>
   <html>
   <head>
     <meta charset=\"utf-8\"/>
     <title>Marked in the browser</title>
   </head>
   <body>
     <div id=\"content\"></div>
     <script \
src=\"https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/marked/marked.min.js\"></script>
     <script>
       document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = marked(``);
     </script>
   </body>
   </html>";


md = "'# Marked in the browser\\n\\nRendered by **marked**.'";


CloudDeploy[
  ExportForm[$mdHtmlTemplate @ md, "HTML"],
  "test/md1"
]
```

[image]